# Converting vue.js app to quasar-framework app

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I would like to convert an existing app made with Vue.js to Quasar framework..

I am scaffolding the Quasar app with 'Quasar init', which creates a blank app. I am migrating the .Vue files from Vuejs to quasar app.

However, the Vuejs app contains 'main.js' at the root of 'src' folder, which I am not sure how to use it in Quasar. I tried to copy the code to 'index.vue' but ended up with errors.

Any idea how to migrate this main.js code to appropriate file in Quasar?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Quasar uses App plugins for this.
From https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-plugins.html

> A common use case for Quasar applications is to run code before the root Vue instance is instantiated.
> Quasar provides an elegant solution to that problem by allowing users to define so-called app plugins.

There are many good examples too:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
    
export default ({ Vue }) => {
  // we add it to Vue prototype
  // so we can reference it in Vue files
  // without the need to import axios
  Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;
    
  // Example: this.$axios will reference Axios now
  //          so you don't need stuff like vue-axios.
  
}
```